# GNU Archimedes fails to build -- Undefined symbols for architecture, even though they are present

Tags: c, compilation, gnu

I'm rather unused to C, and completely new to compiling bigger projects, and I'm having problems trying to build [GNU Archimedes](https://www.gnu.org/software/archimedes/).

I tried the `./configure` and `make` approach, as well as simply executing `gcc -lm archimedes.c -o archimedes` in the `src/` directory, as the documentation suggests. Both give a similar error message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_MM2", referenced from:
      _ParabMEP2D in ccwORAXj.o
      _Hole_MEP2D in ccwORAXj.o
  "_creation", referenced from:
  _EMC in ccwORAXj.o
  "_rnd", referenced from:
      _MCdevice_config in ccwORAXj.o
      _scat in ccwORAXj.o
      _EMC in ccwORAXj.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

`MM2`, `rnd`, and `creation` are functions contained in one of many .h files in `src/`. Every solution to similar sounding problems had issues linking multiple compiled .c files together, but in this case, there's only one .c file.
If it's relevant, the name of the .o file in the error changes with every try.
I've tried building it under macOS (with both clang and gcc, the latter installed via Homebrew) and Fedora Linux, with similar results.

What am I doing wrong? I hope this is the right place to ask, but I have no idea where else to turn. I'm grateful for suggestions.

Thanks in advance and have a good day!

Comment: Have you solved the problem? I am also having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

In the folder /archimedes-2.0.1/src/ go through all header files (.h) and change every "inline" to say "static inline".

This fix was found by Alexander Vogt. His original post is linked to below:

https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/archimedes-discuss/2017-11/msg00000.html

The problem has to do with compatibility issues between older and newer versions of c compilers.